# onClick no Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Fiz um `EditText` com o atributo `text = 100,` porém, quando uso minha função `onClick()`, que tem como objetivo fazer o seguinte calculo `text - 50`, quando clico no botão e executa a rotina o meu aplicativo fecha.

Segue o código:

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button botao1;
    TextView life;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        botao1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        life = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hp);

        botao1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                int ataque = Integer.parseInt(life.getText().toString());
                int ataca = 50;
                life.setText(ataque - 50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Segue o LogCat:

```
 01-18 21:58:14.640 16746-16746/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    01-18 21:58:15.647 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    01-18 21:58:15.705 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub D/Atlas: Validating map...
    01-18 21:58:15.750 16746-16756/poke.pokeclub W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.579ms
    01-18 21:58:15.861 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    01-18 21:58:15.861 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
    01-18 21:58:15.861 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 04/06/15 Mon
    01-18 21:58:15.861 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: 
    01-18 21:58:15.861 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: 
    01-18 21:58:15.861 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: 
    01-18 21:58:15.861 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: 
    01-18 21:58:15.865 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    01-18 21:58:15.976 16746-16798/poke.pokeclub D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    01-18 21:58:16.782 16746-16756/poke.pokeclub W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.420ms
    01-18 21:58:16.998 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub I/Choreographer: Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-18 21:58:19.916 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-18 21:58:20.650 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000032
    01-18 21:58:20.667 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime: Process: poke.pokeclub, PID: 16746
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x32
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4138)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at poke.pokeclub.Principal$1.onClick(Principal.java:36)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    01-18 21:58:20.715 16746-16746/poke.pokeclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta clicando em [edit]

Comment: Adiciona erro no logcat para ter mais informação também

Comment: ta ai os dados que faltavam...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando atribuir um valor `int` no `setText()`, sendo que este método espera [receber uma String](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) ou um `int` representando um id  [correspondente a um recurso](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)), que no caso, não é encontrado(por isso lança um [Resources$NotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException.html)). Tente alterar a linha:

```
life.setText(ataque - 50);
```

para:

```
life.setText(String.valueOf(ataque - 50));
```

**Referências:**

[android.content.res.Resurces$NotFoundException : String resource ID #0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953599/android-content-res-resurcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x0)

[android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID Fatal Exception in Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191092/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-fatal-except)

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/TextView.html